# How to split packets in flash, XMLSocket

Tags: flash, actionscript, split, packet, xmlsocket

Hello I believe my flash client is losing some packets the server sends, because some packets get joined together hence I believe it drops them.

Here is my packetHandler in flash

```
  private var xmlsock:XMLSocket;
  this.xmlsock = new XMLSocket();
  xmlsock.connect("127.0.0.1", 1234);
  this.xmlsock.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, this.packetHandler);


  public function packetHandler(event:DataEvent):void {
   var packet:String = event.data;
   var args:Array = packet.split(":");
   if(args.length <= 0) return;

   switch(args[0]) {
    case 'w': //waiting
     ExternalInterface.call("waiting");
     break;
    case 'u': //user count
     if(args.length >= 2)
      ExternalInterface.call("userCount", args[1]);
     break;
                                //... etc handlers ...
   }
 }
```

A possible packet I sniffed sent by the server was.

u:105.w.       aka              (75 3A 31 30 35 00 77 00)

so the waiting packet never came in.

How would i go about fixing this bug.. I am using XMLSocket

Comment: Not really how else can you use XMLSocket? you build your own server.

But sometimes when packets get flushed they join up into one packet so  it's required to split them by null byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K solved if anyone needs help with this turns out you can just do this

var packets:Array = data.split("\x00");

Answer (score 0):

Use a `flash.net.Socket` instead.